# BufferedInputStream is closed

Tags: android, soap, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am developing an android application which contains a concept of Forgot Password in a login page. I am using Soap Web Service for this application.

This is my code:

```
public void fncCallForgotPasswordService() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.org/ForgotPWD";
        String METHOD_NAME = "ForgotPWD";;
        String NAMESPACE = "http://example.org/";
        String URL = "https://in.xyz.com/abcd.example/MethodExample.asmx";

        try {
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("UID", strUserID);
            Request.addProperty("CID", strCompID);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            resultString = (SoapObject) resultString.getProperty("Data");
            resultString = (SoapObject) resultString.getProperty("Row");
            strMessage = resultString.getPropertyAsString("Message");

            if (resultString != null) {
                Log.i("Message", strMessage);
            }

            Log.i("Result", "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The web service is providing the new password, but the problem is I am getting an exception which says

`org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Invalid stream or encoding: java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed (position:START_DOCUMENT null@1:1) caused by: java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed`

SoapObject 'resultString' shows null when the web service is first called, and the above exception is shown. But when I try for the second or third time in succession, no exception is thrown. Only at the first time when the Forgot Password web service is invoked, it throws the above exception.

Also, I am receiving the new password on my phone with or without the exception.

But I am concerned that why this exception is occurring.

Please Help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to customize the timeout-value apart from the non standard one:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(this.url,this.connectionTimeout)
```

Comment: already implemented. But still no success, still giving the same error.

Comment: did u try wrapping the response??

Comment: can i see ur wsdl file??